Number of outstanding clients of a service/driver IO file on Windows
After a service/driver (.sys) is started, normally communication happens through a file (client pseudo code):
HANDLE gHandle = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\DriverFile",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
... 
DeviceIoControl(gHandle, MY_MSG_ID, NULL, 0, &refCount, 
   sizeof(refCount), &length, NULL);
...
CloseHandle(gHandle);

Is there a way to know how many clients have open connection to the driver file?
One way to impl it, is to handle IRP_MJ_CREATE/IRP_MJ_CLOSE on the driver side and keep ref count manually; then using some message to the driver client code could retrieve the count. Is there a way to do that without involving changes to the driver side?

Just a thought: doesn't invoking Sysinternals' handle -a reveal such information?

Why would that be useful to know? How would your code communicating with the device change if it knew there were other outstanding handles to the device?

@IInspectable in my code I start another process (as admin user) if driver needs to be installed/started. The admin process waits for all clients to be able to close/delete the driver/service when it's not used.

simply invoke driver unload (say ZwUnloadDriver). if no clients on driver devices - it will be just unloaded. if exist open files - it will be marked for unload. when last file will be closed, driver will be unloaded

@RbMm should this be called from the driver itself? Does it simply stop it? In my case when it's all done It should also delete its registration (aka uninstal service, so nothing stays in registry)

@PavelP, no. do this from user mode. simply call ZwUnloadDriver (if you direct register driver in registry and load it by ZwLoadDriver). or use SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP if you work via sc manager (in this case ZwUnloadDriver will be called inside services.exe). and you can delete all driver registration just. system mantain references on device and unload diver when will be no more handles on it device(s)

I don't use ZwLoadDriver or anything like that. I use pretty much the same code as WinRing0 does: CreateService + StartService followed by CreateFile

you in any case use ZwLoadDriver , and ZwUnloadDriver, simply indirect. services.exe call it for you. and this nothing change , ok, i paste answer

you not need any reference counting (the system already do this for you) and not need wait for clients. if you want unload/delete driver - simply do this. if still exist opened files on driver (more exactly on some it device) system unload driver, when last file will be closed.
let do demo with Null.sys driver. try stop/unload it, until exist opened files on it device ( \Device\Null ).
HRESULT StopDriver(_In_ PCWSTR lpServiceName, _In_ PCWSTR lpDriverName)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    if (SC_HANDLE hSCManager = HR(hr, OpenSCManagerW(0, 0, 0)))
    {
        SC_HANDLE hService = HR(hr, OpenServiceW(hSCManager, lpServiceName, SERVICE_STOP));

        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);

        if (hService)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS ss;

            HR(hr, ControlService(hService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ss));

            CloseServiceHandle(hService);

            if (NOERROR == hr && SERVICE_STOP_PENDING == ss.dwCurrentState)
            {
                while (STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH == 
                    (hr = DoesDriverObjectExist(lpDriverName)))
                {
                    Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    switch (hr)
    {
    case ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE:
    case STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND:
        hr = S_OK;
        break;
    default:
        DbgPrint("error = %x\n", hr);
        break;
    }

    return hr;
}

for check are driver in memory we can use next function
NTSTATUS DoesDriverObjectExist(PCWSTR lpDriverName)
{
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObjectName, lpDriverName);
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    NTSTATUS status = NtOpenFile(&oa.RootDirectory, SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &iosb, 0, 0);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        __debugbreak();// this never must be !
        NtClose(oa.RootDirectory);
    }
    return status;
}

in case Null.sys the \Driver\Null object will be, until driver in memory. we can try open this object with NtOpenFile. we fail in any case (impossible open driver object from user mode and with this api). but error code will be different.
STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH - mean that \Driver\Null exist and STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND - mean that \Driver\Null not exist
for simulate client during driver stop we can use next code
ULONG WINAPI ClientThread(HANDLE hEvent)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(L"\\\\?\\NUL", 0, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    
    SetEvent(hEvent);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, 0, L"\\\\?\\NUL", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }

    return 0;
}

void mmm()
{
    if (HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0))
    {
        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, ClientThread, hEvent, 0, 0))
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);

            WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
        }

        CloseHandle(hEvent);
    }

    StopDriver(L"Null", L"\\Driver\\Null");
}

so we first start client and wait until it open device on Null.sys ( L"\\\\?\\NUL" ) and then try stop driver - StopDriver(L"Null", L"\\Driver\\Null"); because we wait here for demo - we will be spin in loop, until messagebox in ClientThread will be not closed. in real code - you usual not need call DoesDriverObjectExist and wait for other value than STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH - you can simply delete service or dont care at all. all this code - for demo and better understand all.
and util function
template <typename T> 
T HR(HRESULT& hr, T t)
{
    hr = t ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
    return t;
}


NUL is a special name in windows. Is that intentional, or simply coincidence? Perhaps, should use some other name to avoid confusion

@PavelP null.sys create device \Device\Null and symbolick link for it \GLOBAL??\NUL so we can use name or link for open device. if be i write code for self - i simply use NtOpenFile and \Device\Null . if want use CreateFileW - use or "\\\\?\\NUL" or "\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\Null" and in any case this is demo only. you have another driver and device names

@PavelP is a special name in windows. - no, not true. usual name as any another. and this is exact name "\\?\NUL" for CreateFileW ( or can use \\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\Null ) or can use \Device\Null with NtOpenFile
